# Overloading the greater than operator and using it to find the greatest value in an array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I can not wrap my head around this, the mathematic part is giving me problems, can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class soccerPlayer{
private:
    int jnum;
    int goals;
    int assist;
public:
    soccerPlayer(int, int, int);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, soccerPlayer&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, soccerPlayer&);
    soccerPlayer operator>(soccerPlayer);


};
soccerPlayer soccerPlayer::operator>(soccerPlayer socc){

}
soccerPlayer::soccerPlayer(int num, int go, int assit){
    jnum = num;
    goals = go;
    assist = assit;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, soccerPlayer& soc){
    out << soc.jnum << endl << soc.goals << endl << soc.assist << endl;
    return out;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, soccerPlayer& socca){
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter jersey number: ";
    in >> socca.jnum;
    cout << "Enter number of goals: ";
    in >> socca.goals;
    cout << "Enter number of assists: ";
    in >> socca.assist;
    cout << endl;
    return in;
}


int main()
{
    soccerPlayer soc(75, 33, 50), soc2(44, 60, 80), soc3(65, 23, 44), soc4(55, 34, 12), soc5(45,102, 22),
    soc6(36, 22, 77), soc7(27, 12, 24), soc8(38,90, 9), soc9(88, 51, 15), soc10(99, 29, 104), soc11(78, 61, 5);

    return 0;
};
```

b. Include an operator>()function for the class. One SoccerPlayer is considered greater
than another if the sum of goals plus assists is greater.
c. Create an array of 11 SoccerPlayers, then use the > operator to find the player who has
the greatest total of goals plus assists.

Comment: taking the specification you were given literally, `operator >` must return `true` if `this->goals + this->assist > other.goals + other.assist`. Write that code. And your signature for `operator>` is wrong, it should be `bool soccerPlayer::operator>(const soccerPlayer& socc) const { ... }`

Comment: As for the second bit: you currently have eleven different variables instead of an array. You want something of the form `soccerPlayer players[]` or maybe an `std::vector<soccerPlayer>`

Comment: btw is is more common to implement an `operator<`. Most algorithms use `<` (not `>`). For example if your assigment allows you can use `std::max_element` to find the max (and this algorithm by default excpets a `opertor<` not an `operator>`)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Add some getter functions so you can access the `goals` and `assists` outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

As it is it appears you have not attempted to write the code for finding the greatest player. With that in mind I will give you a thought to how to solve it while I will not clearly tell you how to solve it as it should be a learning experience for you. You may think about it in simpler terms. Lets say that the best player is the one who scored the most goals. We can have an array `playerGoals = []` which contains the number of goals for each player so say `playerGoals = [3, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 0]` this means that player 0 has scored 3 goals and so on. Something you might try is looping through the array and comparing each number to the previous largest number so lets say something like

```
most_goals = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < playerGoals.size(); i++){
    if (playerGoals[i] > most_goals){
        most_goals = playersGoals[i];
        // Here you can also save the index if you want it
    }
}
```

That is the logic to what you want to do.
I have not solved it for you on purpose, rather I gave you a little thinking with guidance. I hope this helps you solve the problem on your own.

Comment: the assigment says the one should write a `operator>` to solve it

Comment: I am not solving the posters homework problems. I will however provide insight into how the mathematics work for such a question of finding the best player.

Comment: I am just trying to get help in understanding this, I do not want anyone to do my homework for me. Im confused on how to make the class array to where it will hold all three values for jersey number, amount of goals and amount of assists, and then use those values inside of the overloaded greater than operator. Usually once i start to understand the method it all becomes clear but I am drawing a blank at the  moment.

Comment: Like Botje said above - you want to create an array of `std::vector<soccerPlayer>` then each index in the vector represents a player, and you can use the `soccerPlayer` class and its methods to access the `goals`, `assits` and `jnum`

Comment: How would I call this:

Comment: ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, soccerPlayer& player)
{
    out<<"Jersey Number: " << player.jnum << "Goals: " << player.goals << "Assist: " << player.assist;
    return out;
}

Comment: down here: cout << "Highest player score: ";

Comment: I have most of the code and the array right, but the assignment says i have to use an overloaded output operator to display